# remote Docker Repository behaviour in Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

I have a remote docker repository configured in Artifactory (to docker hub). To test it I've created docker image A and pushed it to docker hub.

The image is `user-name/image:latest`.
Now I can pull it from artifactory using `artifactory-url/docker/user-name/image:latest`.

Now I've updated image A to image B and pushed it to docker hub. When I remove my local images and pull this image again from Artifactory I still get the image A (so it seems the cache is used). When I set the following setting to zero (Metadata Retrieval Cache Period) I'll pull the updated image B.

All fine. Now I increase the Metadata Retrieval Cache Period setting again. I've now deleted the image from docker hub and try to pull it again using artifactory. This fails while I was hoping it would just pull the image from the Artifactory cache?

I can also not pull it using the cache directly: `docker pull artifactory-url/docker-cache/user-name/image:latest`.

Is there a way to use a docker image from artifactory which is deleted in the remote repository?

Comment: what is the artifactory version you are using ?

Comment: @error404 6.8.6

Answer (score 0):

The first part you wrote is ok and its the expected behavior. Now, for the second part, it's also the expected behavior and I will explain why - when you use a virtual repository as your Artifactory Docker registry, it will always search for artifacts in the local repositories first, then in the remote-cache, and only then in the remote itself. However, if Artifactory finds the package in the local or remote-cache repositories, **it will always also check the remote for newer versions**. This causes cached images that are deleted from the remote itself to not be downloadable from the remote-cache in Artifactory, since Artifactory receives a 404 error from the remote repository. You can fix this by moving the image to the local repository, and you will be able to pull it.